# Row filter crashes C# app with System.Data.EvaluateException was unhandled message

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I'm trying to add a row filter feature on my datagridview but keep getting the following error message:

```
System.Data.EvaluateException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.
```

This happens every time I type something into my textbox. Any idea why? Code is as follows:

**App.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SpeedyRent.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Form1.cs**

```
    // driver no search

    private void driverNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "DriverNo like '%" + driverNo.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

Comment: Side comment: I don't think making an infinitely-deep hierarchy of nested BindingSources is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks - what would you suggest instead? This is what I've come across on forums

Comment: Simplest is to always use one BindingSource, then just set the Filter property on it accordingly, rather than making new ones and nesting.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how this would look?

Comment: DriverNo  is int .. you need to convert this to string for like operation

Comment: @Priyank - tried that below with @Ankush's answer - got the following error message `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

Comment: Just set the binding source once where you populate the data, then in this code just get that binding source (`BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource; bs.Filter = "...";`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Form1.cs

```
    private void driverNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(driverNo.Text))
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        int _driverNo;

        if (int.TryParse(driverNo.Text,out _driverNo))
            ((DataTable)DataGridViews.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "DriverNo = " + _driverNo;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid driver no.");
    }
```

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier Change is `"DriverNo like %" + driverNo.Text + "%";` just do replace ur old code with this and reRun code again.I remove "'" from filter string.

Comment: Thanks - I now get the following error message `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

Comment: This works initially but when the textbox is cleared (i.e. to make way for another entry) it crashes with the `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

Comment: Now I added required condition before changing datasource of datagridview. Check now for every input values.

Comment: Ok it works well - but two things: 1) when the textbox is empty/cleared, there seems to be no way to view all all the results (since no search filter is applied), 2) it crashes whenever I type in an letter

Comment: I'm getting the following error message - `No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments` at `if (int.TryParse(driverNo.Text))`

Comment: This is different from @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier 's question. This does an exact `=` comparison where the question wanted to do `LIKE`. Is this an acceptable difference?